# Pythonではてなブックマークのデータ管理のページからブックマークデータを取得したい。

Tags: python, python3, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49506/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%83%96%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AEurl%E3%81%A8%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%85%A8%E9%83%A8python%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/49549#49549)でスクレイピングを使用して取り出そうと考えていたのですが、はてなサイトに何度もアクセスを飛ばすのは良くないと思いデータの管理画面からブックマークデータをダウンロードしてそこから抽出しようと思うのですが、どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

[image: はてなデータ管理画面]

三つのうちのどれでも良いのですが、HTMLでDLできるブックマーク形式が楽かと思います。

requestsを使用しそのURLにアクセスすればダウンロードが始まるのかと考えたのですが、URLが明らかに固定ではなさそうなのでどのようにアクセスして良いのかわかりません。

ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

```
http://b.hatena.ne.jp/dump?mode=bookmarks
```

ログイン画面が出てくるのですがパスワードを打ってもログイン出来ません。

[image: ログイン画面]

追記
[はてなのapiを使用すると全件取得](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/help/entry/api)できるようなのですが、以下の文章の意味がよく分からないです。
具体的にはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

> WSSE認証を用いたブックマークデータの取得
>   自分のブックマークに投稿したブックマークデーターはエクスポート機能により一括でダウンロードすることが可能となっております。(データのエクスポートは設定画面より可能です。)
>
> このデータのエクスポートを外部プログラムからも行えるよう、エクスポート用URIは Cookie 認証以外に
>   はてなブックマークAtomAPIに同じくWSSE認証での認証が行えるようになっています。各フォーマットごとのエクスポートURI (例えば
>   Atomフィードでのエクスポートの URI は http://b.hatena.ne.jp/dump) になりますが、この URI に対して
>   WSSE 認証を行うことでブラウザ以外のプログラムからでも直接データのダウンロードが可能です。

Comment: 基本的にはブラウザでいずれかのデータを一旦ダウンロードして、そのデータ(ローカルに保存したファイル)に対してプログラムからアクセスすることを想定しているはずです。

Comment: Requestsなどを使用できないと言う事でしょうか？

Comment: 最終的な目的次第かと思います。**スクレイピング**が目的であるなら、エクスポートを行う際にも前回質問の回答にもある通り、はてなへのログイン状態で適切なRequestsを行う必要があります。あるいは**自身のはてブデータをPythonで扱う**のが目的で、スクレイピングはあくまでそのデータを取得する下処理なだけであるなら、ブラウザから直接エクスポートで済ませてしまった方が早いですよね。

Comment: はてブのブックマークをpythonで取得して自動でツイートできるようにしたいのです。firebaseのサービスでデータファイルを保存してその後にプログラムで解析をかけてDBに保存ができるようなのですが、保存せずそのまま解析してDBに保存したいです。

Comment: どのライブラリーを使用してダウンロードしたら良いのかわかりません。

Comment: はてなブックマークAtom APIはもうすぐにサポートが終了します。http://bookmark.hatenastaff.com/entry/2018/09/19/181818 それで、はてなブックマーク REST API を使う必要があります。その説明は次のリンクです。http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ja/documents/bookmark/apis/rest そこでは WSSE認証は使えません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このversionというのは具体的にどのようなものを渡せば良いのでしょうか？http://api.b.hatena.ne.jp/{version}/my/bookmark

Comment: バージョン「2013年8月現在、バージョン1が提供されています。」と記載があるので1ではないでしょうか。

Comment: http://api.b.hatena.ne.jp/1/my/bookmarkでやってみたのですが、401 Unauthorizedと表示されて上手くデータが返ってるようにはみえないのですがこれはOAuth認証していないからなのでしょうか？